# Syntax highlighting language hints

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Do you think it would be worthwhile to provide hints as to what language to use for the syntax highlighting?

Sometimes I find the highlighting on SQL or VB.NET answers is more distracting than helpful; for example:

- [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158)
- [Retrieving data from a VB.NET arraylist of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062320)

to pick the two I've been looking at recently.

Comment: Marking as [status-completed] per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting, but see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify.

Comment: Why is this status completed? Was something implemented to let us choose the language? Any SQL with a backslash in quotes ala `'\'` makes the rest of the code act as though it is inside a string.

Comment: @Emtcuifor This is complete per http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/130044 Explicit syntax is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63800/130044

Comment: For **quick reference**: `<!-- language: lang-php -->` or  `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->` or  `<!-- language: lang-none -->` ...etc.  (also, here's the [**language list**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/370758).)

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Note that this question is a bit obsolete, because we now infer prettify language type based on the tags.

See more:
[Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

This is now implemented. In addition to tag inference, you can *manually* specify the language as a hint to [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

The spec is:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

You may use either a **tag** or a **prettify language code** to specify, though prettify language codes are always guaranteed to work regardless of what language the tag happens to be set to.

Use `<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag -->` to use the given highlighting for all the following code blocks.

#### practical examples

For those with little time...

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<!-- language: typescript -->
<!-- language: c# -->
```

Please note they're all in **lower case**, even though the language may be uppercase (C#) or mixed case (TypeScript).

Suppress any syntax highlighting (prevents poor, misleading guesses)

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

Use `language-all` and your syntax highlighting choice shall be used for all code blocks that follow:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
```

**Available Language Hints Moved**

> Due to several lists of available hints existing throughout Meta, the entire list has been consolidated and moved to the following FAQ:
>
> [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I think the current solution with the tag intelligence is a big improvement to what it was before. Especially VB code will look much better now. The only downside is non-language specific questions, that might get answers in VB.NET.

Comment: @awe indeed it will be formatted as a comment, unless you mix language tags and force default inference again.. looks fine to me, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801650/ctype-nullreferenceexception-when-trying-to-upload-a-picture

Comment: Can we get this documented in the help pages?  I've been looking around for this for a while and this is the first place I've found it, so if it is in help pages somewhere it's not visible enough.

Comment: @old you somehow missed it, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting -- same on all Stack Exchange sites

Comment: @Jeff, my bad. I was looking for something related to "language" and I was looking on Ask Different where it's near the bottom.

Comment: Great, thanks. But why do all the magic strings start `lang-`?

Comment: Thank you. FYI of all the solutions described here, only the `<!-- language-all: lang-tag -->` option worked for me. :/

Comment: Is there any highlighter for DOS/Win shell scripts?

Comment: I wish we had this functionality built-in into post editor on SO. I always end up googling this and copy/pasting from this answer, which is counter-productive.

Comment: It's also far too sensitive - `<!--language-all: ... -->` doesn't work - no space before `language`. I end up at this post _every single time I need this_. Very frustrating that it's not in the editor and/or more forgiving

Comment: OMG I forget this thing every time... I've been back on this page for 145th time. They should bring some UI for language selection.

Comment: I suggest using simpler markup like GitHub's triple backtick - language or similar. I also have to google this every time.

Comment: Could you PLEASE hand out 2-3 actual examples?, i.e. `<!-- language: lang-js -->` (Indent before already or still on baserline) does not work... so I simply didn't get you. Also applies to [the referenced feature post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: I've googled this question over 10 times now. This syntax is impossible to remember for some reason. Can't remember if its `lang` or `language`, can't remember if it's `lang-python` `language-python` `lang-py` `python-lang` or just `python` or some other thing. At least I can remember that its `<!-- -->` and not `<-- --!>`

Comment: Where is a list of all the available language tags?

Comment: Google Code Pretty is no longer maintained: https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/commit/e006587b4a893f0281e9dc9a53001c7ed584d4e7. Since there are still bugs which won't be fixed anymore, any plans to migrate to a different highlighter?

Comment: I'm surprised this post said `<!-- language: ts -->` works.  Using neither the comment syntax nor the triple backtick syntax have ever allowed me to omit the `lang-` prefix--something I'd really like if they fixed.

Answer (score 15):

One thing that works now, is to have no highlighting (none being better than wrong) by using `<pre>` *code* `</pre>`.

Comment: agreed - this is worth pointing out

Comment: Has the added downside that you have to escape any `<`/`>` in there.

Comment: And how does one escape an `<`?

Comment: @MPelletier: Use the entity "lt" (with the usual "&" prefix and ";" suffix). (Not just writing it, because I'm not sure how comments are escaped.)

Comment: But wouldn't that just show up as "& lt ;" in your code, since `pre` stands for preformatted?

Comment: OK, so yes, that shows up as <. Then how could one print &lt; for just that?

Comment: @MPelletier: You use the entity `amp` to create a `&`.

Comment: You have to use `<PRE><code>code goes here</code></PRE>` (yes, uppercase `<PRE>`) if you want syntax highlighting. You need to escape `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;` and `&` to `&amp;`.

Comment: Note that it appears that [`<!-- language: none -->`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) is now [the preferred mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85379/formatting-preview-is-not-accurate-for-code-blocks-in-numbered-lists/85410#85410) to disable syntax highlighting for a preformatted block of text.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Thank you so much for `<PRE><code>`.  I've been looking everywhere for basic highlighting!  May be worthy of its own answer because the recommended technique only works in some circumstances.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 14):

There are problems with code-prettify,

```
this [^\s>/] == "example" # is highlighted as a regex, not a comment, 1 / 2
```

..but it mostly does a really good job

There's no good solution to this, Markdown does not provide a way to specify what language a code-block is (see [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode)), so StackOverflow would need to implement their own way.

In the past I've modified a markdown parser to look for a special first-line, something like..

```
{{language:python}}
import os
print os.listdir()
```

The usability problem then is, there's no way to know which languages are supported, or how I should specify say, Visual Basic .NET - should it be `visualbasicnet`, `visual-basic.net`, `vb.net` `vbnet`, etc..?

I suppose this could be overcome by making the code-block button ask for a language (or maybe add second specific-language-code button), but then the site isn't using Markdown anymore, it's using StackOverflows own non-standard version..

Comment: If you were wanting to be really flash, you could see what languages the question was tagged as, and use this as a heuristic.

People with sufficient rep could then do any association for new tags, (it may also encourage more consistent tagging) - still wouldn't always get it right for the "I'm trying to convert this perl to vb.net" type of question, mind you...

Comment: I like the use the tags idea. it would cover most right

Comment: I agree that making SO stop being markdown would be bad. that said if you could embded it as something that is legit html...?
Even then I prefer Rowland's idea

Comment: *@dbr* - Not knowing what language could also be solved with documentation.

Comment: marked down for defeatist attitude.

Answer (score 12):

Last I know, the site used a whitelist approach to strip the unsupported tags or unsupported attributes on tags.
So I think it would be easy to **at least** let us provide the `class` attribute for the `pre` tag (right now, it doesn't). That way, we can manually set the language for the syntax highlighting like this :

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-sql"><code>
--sql comment here
</code></pre>
```

To answer the question ; Yes, it would definitely be worthwhile to provide hints as to what language to use for the syntax highlighting. I mean take a look at [ask.sqlservercentral.com](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/) or [ask.sqlteam.com](http://ask.sqlteam.com/), both of them are [stackexchange sites](http://www.stackexchangesites.com/) focused on SQL Server. But none of the code examples are highlighted correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't the `class` attribute go on the `code` tag? I'm assuming that's what you meant.

Comment: @Jon Seigel, It works both on `pre` tag and `code` tag.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround for VB is to add an additional apostrophe ' at the end of every comment line, so that the daft syntax highlighter thinks you've terminated your string.

```
Dear MarkDown
  'Unterminated 
  Why Is Half My Code Red, It Is Not A String
End Moan
```

Becomes

```
Dear MarkDown
  'Terminated '
  This Is How It Should Look
End Moan
```

I sometimes edit other peoples' posts to add the apostrophes.

---

**EDIT** based on Joel's suggestion to use `''#` which is even better:

```
Dear MarkDown
  ''# Terminated 
  This Is How It Should Look
End Moan
```

Comment: A better workaround is to use `''#` to indicate comments. This avoids need to worry about escaping quotes in the comment itself and actually colors the text like a comment rather than a string literal.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn — This is ugly.

Comment: @MarkJ — You degrade other people’s code to make the buggy syntax highlighter work ??

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn — Altering the code to circumvent the bugs of the syntax highlighter. I had never seen that.

Answer (score 5):

Adding in an option for very light highlighting that would essentially do little more than colour brackets and isolated literals, treat '' and "" as text delimiters and nothing else would be useful for a vast number of languages currently unsupported.

Functional example code look like crap with the current highlighter as do punctuation-light languages like SQL. Perl is just hilarious.

Actually thinking about it more you wouldn't even want the text stuff. It is too costly a hit to readability when it fails (thinking generic type parameters in F# for example).

Essentially nothing that requires unbounded state and never goes across a new line should function very well. Something that is unbounded but the bounds are highly common like whitespace, new lines, any non-word character, etc. have a high probability of not messing up many languages.

Comment: Was going to point out that in some languages ' is not a string delimiter, and -- isn't always "decrement". Can't say I've seen many Perl questions on SO (Guess everyone still uses perlmonks), but I'd fear how it would handle regexp delimiters...

Answer (score 5):

As I've already said in [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41419/allow-class-attribute-for-code-tag/41459#41459), this could be helped if the language could be inferred from the tags. That way, this fix would work retroactively, and the work flow wouldn't change.

I know that prettify does have a way to specify the language, it would be only a matter of using that.

Comment: Yes, that is also a possibility.  However, this would not help for posts containing snippets in several languages (e.g. SQL + PHP, or JavaScript + Perl, or C + Lisp).  It also seems to be a much more involved code change than adding to the HTML whitelist.

Comment: @Svante - it would still help those if the list of _possibles_ is filtered down to those tags.  Then for example you might have a php and sql question, but at least it's not gonna try to color the sql like C.

Answer (score 5):

Scavenger's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/43775#43775) is a good idea, but `#` might be something that is valid in the code like a pre-processor command in `C++` that can be part of the actual code sample.

I suggest to have something that is specified *before* the code block in a special way. The code block is indented with 4 spaces, so the language specifier could be indented 3 spaces (and only mean something when appearing immediately before a code block). This follows the simplicity in the markup rules that already exists.

> VB.NET
>        Dim myVariable As String 'Here is the first code line
>        myVariable = "Hello world"

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest syntax I think would be something like this:

```
# Python:

import this
this.eat()
```

That is, a language-specific comment mark, space, language identifier on the first line. Of course, "Py", "Python 2.6" and misspellings like "Pyton" should work as well.

Comment: Not sure how this would work with `inline code` samples?

Comment: It wouldn't. Shouldn't inline code should be short enough to grasp without coloring anyway?

Comment: As it is, inline code samples are not highlighted anyway (just styled with monospace font and grey background...)

Comment: I am of the firm belief that misspellings should _not_ work.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround for VB comments is to include two apostrophes and a pound symbol at the beginning of the line.  That way, comments aren't highlighted as text and they stand out better.

```
''# You're commenting!
Dim c As New Comment()
```

see [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/vb-net-syntax-highligting-does-not-properly-support-comment).

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone seen how terribly this general syntax works for MATLAB? Look at the last piece of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530782/how-do-i-manipulate-data-in-the-following-manner). MATLAB uses apostrophe (`'`) as a matrix transposition operator. As a result, everything in code following it is highlighted as a string in brown.

Comments in MATLAB start with a `%` and those never get highlighted either. Perhaps we could at least make separate HTML tags for certain languages like `<asm></asm>` or `<matlab></matlab>`. This would be very helpful, because posting a non-ugly MATLAB question or answer takes ages of reformatting your original code. I personally volunteer to write the code to implement this, just tell me what to do.

Comment: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html; also see [Jeff's answer above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)