# Syntax highlighter misbehaves with PostScript code

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, source-code

This is probably not the most important thing, but since uservoice is closed, here's a feature request.

The syntax highlighter for code blocks really screws up on PostScript code, making it essentially less readable then unhighlited code (and that's pretty hard with Postcript). And, after all, PostScript is a programming language :-)

What do you think?

**Edit:** Looking closer, it would go a long way if the prettyfier would at least recognize the precent symbol as a comment starter.

On a side note: To the right of this input box it says

> If your question is about this
>   website, ask it on
>   meta.stackoverflow.com instead.

This could lead to a mental infinite recursion.

Comment: Well, the box used to refer to **meta.meta.stackoverflow.com** which is a *much* more nasty recursion :)

Comment: Possible dup? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints

Comment: @ChrisF: I had seen that question, but don't consider at a dupe.

Comment: @Ian Elliott: No, that just leads to a name server error -- recursion stopped by exception :-)

Comment: Can you post an example? The syntax highlighter messes up on several languages, but I haven't seen any mistakes that are particularly egregious.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078770/array-searching-code-challenge/1079109#1079109 I know it's code golf, so it's rather pathological, but anyway...

Comment: You'd need to tell the syntax highlighter what language you were in to really fix up the highlighting (hence http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints), otherwise you risk breaking another, more widely asked about language

Comment: Syntax highlighter misbehaves for most non-trivial languages.

Comment: @Ian: and if it did get to meta-SO, you'd eventually just reach a real SO when the URL got too long...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the syntax highlighter, bug reports should go to the Google Code Prettifier project instead.