# Would it be possible for the syntax highlighter to allow for SQL capitalization?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed that the syntax highlighter for code samples does not work with capitalization for SQL.  I just posted a question on SO and had to spend a couple extra seconds to modify it to get the highlighting to work...  Is this supposed to work?

[How to count the number of times a character appears in a SQL column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144172/how-count-the-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-a-sql-column)

Would it be possible to add this to the keywords list?

- SELECT
- WHERE
- FROM
- INNER
- OUTER
- JOIN
- LEFT
- RIGHT
- TOP
- ORDER BY
- GROUP BY

*I know there are others that would be useful, but didn't want to run through the entire list*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would have be submitted as a patch to Google Prettify

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 2):

With [the syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints), you can now splendour your eyeballs on the colours of the keywords per whatever language tag is riding shotgun on the question.

You can also override the default colouring inferred from the tags on the question with a prettify hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

So an example case in SQL would look like:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    SELECT mischief FROM sendak WHERE theWildThings='Imagination'
```

Answer (score 0):

UPPER CASE in SQL is relict of the past...
BTW, are COBOL keywords being displayed properly? :)

Comment: Yet it seems to be the default syntax used in all of the SQL tools...  Right click table, select top 1000....  Yields capitalization in keywords...

Comment: Hang on... upper case is old hat but case sensitivity is modern?

Comment: @gbn: well, yeah... I mean, case sensitivity wasn't really necessary prior to the introduction of lower-case letters...

Comment: @Shog9. Perhaps it's because we dev dbas get used to SHOUTING at client devs all the time ;-)