# Stack Overflow syntax highlighting

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

When using SO's code blocks, can you control how syntax highlighting is performed? Many times, I've pasted (for example) [some shell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255099/whats-the-proper-use-of-printf-to-display-pointers-padded-with-0s/1255179#1255179) into an SO answer, and the syntax highlighting has been completely unrelated. Is there any way to turn it off, or to change the language used?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There *is* a way to completely turn off code highlighting: use <strike>`<code>`</strike> tags (I often do this for OCaml/Lisp/Haskell code where unmatched `'`s cause problems). **EDIT:** As random pointed out, `<pre>` will work better than `<code>`.

Normal highlighting:

```js
return 'a' "x" void
```

With `<pre>` it looks like this:

```
return 'a' "x" void
```

Keep in mind that with `<pre>`, you don't need to indent your code by four spaces. For example, the code in this answer is formatted like this:

````
Normal highlighting with four spaces:

    return 'a' "x" void

or with ```language:

```js
return 'a' "x" void
```

With `<pre>` it looks like this:

<pre>
return 'a' "x" void
</pre>
````

(Sorry about the highlighting but I can't do this in `<pre>`...)

Comment: If you want the nice background, use `PRE`

Comment: Note that it appears that [`<!-- language: none -->`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) is now [the preferred mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85379/formatting-preview-is-not-accurate-for-code-blocks-in-numbered-lists/85410#85410) to disable syntax highlighting for a preformatted block of text.

Comment: I hope, my proposed edit enriches the post.

Comment: There is also the newer [code fence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-wok/184109#184109),  ```lang-none.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot control how the syntax is highlighted.

SO, uses Google's prettify to do the syntax coloring.  Prettify uses common language patterns to determine syntax coloring.

For example:

Comments:

```
// comment
#comment
```

Strings:

```
'This is a string'
"So is this"
```

Key words:

```
void
return
int 
bool
```

As [Zifre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/stackoverflow-syntax-highlighting/13471#13471) says.  You can turn off the syntax highlighting in code by using the `<pre>` tags around your desired block of code.

Comment: So this is a problem *upstream*?

Comment: Hmm... it looks like prettify has the ability to specify a language using a lang-* css class.

Comment: Didn't work for me.... `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">` made the code a complete mess.