# Is it possible to explicitly tell Stack Overflow the language of the code block you are including?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [stackoverflow syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/stackoverflow-syntax-highlighting)
>   [Syntax highlighting hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints)

Stack Overflow awesomely detects what language a code block is and syntax highlights it accordingly. But sometimes it fails. Is it possible to explicitly tell it what the language is?

php:

```
if ( force_ssl_admin() && !is_ssl() ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
        wp_redirect(preg_replace('|^http://|', 'https://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

ruby:

```
def destroy
  @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
  @payment.destroy

  redirect_to :back
end
```

yaml (FAIL)

```
foo: this is foo!
bar: this is bar!
id: 5
```

Comment: This is a good question, but it belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com  You would get a much better answer there.  To my knowledge, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask it there. Do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: The answer is most definitely no.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints

Comment: No. A similar question is here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/stackoverflow-syntax-highlighting

Comment: The greasemonkey script [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41779/greasemonkey-script-to-specify-the-language-for-the-syntax-highlighter) does what you want.