# Python syntax highlighting breaks on quotation mark

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

A quote mark (') in a comment breaks further highlighting. Example: [Is there a tool to check database integrity in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734645/is-there-a-tool-to-check-database-integrity-in-django)

Comment: Have a read of the markdown help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) (probably more accurately a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55344/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't actually using the python syntax highlighter. I fixed it by adding

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
```

before the code to force python syntax highlighting.