# Why is the syntax highlighting for this question's code all red?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464955/why-is-the-return-value-of-an-empty-python-regexp-search-a-match), and the code is displaying all in red (the colour normally reserved for strings).

I could perhaps understand no syntax highlighting (though the question is tagged Python), but why red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag to do the syntax highlighting, not the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag:

```
<pre class="lang-regex prettyprint">
  <code>
    <span class="str">import re<br>
```

Given the list of languages in [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), which *does* include Python (as `py`), it seems Python is not recognized as a language (yet) to get it the correct `lang-py` class.

Though it is [in Jeff's list](http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK), Python-only questions currently use `default` rather than `lang-py`, [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465496/dont-understand-python-pop-altering-multiple-variables):

```
<pre class="default prettyprint">
  <code>
    <span class="pln">... </span>
```

Even more surprising: it seems to me that `lang-regex` is not even supported [by Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)? But I guess I'm looking at some old list.

Comment: But why? I thought if a question had two language tags, it would use "default".

Comment: Aha, maybe `python` needs to be known as `py`, to be recognized as Python, @sepp2k? Other Python-only questions, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465231/urllib2-exception-handling-with-couchdb), seem to be rendered as `default`, not as `lang-py`.

Comment: Strange. [python] shows up in [Jeff's list of tag mappings](http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK) (line 12), but maybe something went wrong with it

Comment: I was just looking at that list too, @Michael. Surely `regex` is there too, but I fail to find any clue about support for `lang-regex` in the list of [Prettify-supported languages](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)...

Answer (score 1):

We have switched both python and regex to use the "default" prettify syntax highlighting.  Regex was supported in prettify however wasn't creating the most ideal output.

Comment: Did you already make that switch 30 minutes ago? As then Python was already rendering as `default` anyhow -- which seems odd, unless of course you were working on it.

Comment: Python was already set to default.

Comment: What's the reason for setting python to default? Doesn't that mean that if I tag a question e.g. C# and python ("What's the python equivalent for this C# feature"), it'll be highlighted as C#? Wouldn't this problem just as easily be fixed by setting python to python, so python+regex gives the default highlighting because it has two language tags?

Comment: What's the reason for setting Python to "default"? Does this mean that "<!-- language: lang-py -->" has no effect? I'm confused because Jeff has included "lang-py" in [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax/81973#81973) and [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually/81971#81971) but not in [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface/81970#81970), [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax/75019#75019) or [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41419/allow/41434#41434).