# Syntax highlighting: what about answering with a different language than the one used in the question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes, it can be useful to quote a different language to the one used in the question. For example, one might be interested in the C source code of a language interpreter in order to understand how it works and to find an answer to ones original question.

See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038803/function-local-read-only-vs-global-read-only-variable-with-the-same-name/5039040#5039040) as an example.

An [override syntax has been proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify). When will it be implemented? Will it fit this use case?

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works on sites for which it has been enabled. If it's not active on your site, ask for it on your meta.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is now implemented. In addition to tag inference (a recent change), you can *manually* specify the language as a hint to [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

The spec is:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

You may use either a **tag** or a **prettify language code** to specify, though prettify language codes are always guaranteed to work regardless of what language the tag happens to be set to.

The complete list of supported prettify code languages is:

- lang-none
- lang-default
- lang-bsh
- lang-c
- lang-cpp
- lang-cs
- lang-csh
- lang-css
- lang-hs
- lang-html
- lang-java
- lang-js
- lang-lisp
- lang-lua
- lang-ml
- lang-perl
- lang-php
- lang-proto
- lang-py
- lang-rb
- lang-scala
- lang-sh
- lang-sql
- lang-vb
- lang-xml

Comment: this does not seem to be working for me for "none" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187607/how-can-i-make-specflow-cope-nicely-with-dates-times

Comment: cs or csh is c#?

Comment: @TDaver: I believe it is `cs`.  `csh` would be the shell I would think.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: could you please add one for Java's property files? `lang-sh` seemed appropriate but doesn't do anything. It should highlight the "=" and use a different colour for "#"-comments.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I tried `<!-- language: lang-sh -->` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322632/spring-expression-language-spel-with-value-dollar-vs-hash-vs), but it didn't work.

Comment: +1 for the language none! Comes in handy.. when you don't want highlighted stuff to be color coded!

Comment: @sjngm did you put one blank line between the `<!-- language ... -->` and the code block itself?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I had it without one and just tried with one, but it only colours the numbers differently.

Comment: @sjngm that's right... but it's not in our hands, that's how the external tool is coloring that language. You can mess around with this in the sandbox: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/72039#72039

Comment: @Jeff what's the best way to contribute a new language to that list?  I'm mainly interested in pascal like syntax highlighting, and I'm willing to make the contribution myself.

Comment: @jach do it at http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/