# Format (chosen colours) of Gherkin code is not very good

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, code-formatting

See this [quesions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187607/how-can-i-make-specflow-cope-nicely-with-dates-times), words like "for" should not be put in blue etc

Answer (score 1):

Now that [the language can be set to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one) “none” for a block of code, there is a way to get a reasonable result.

Comment: You can just use `<pre>` blocks to do that