# Java syntax highlighting not shown

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261205/hide-system-specific-details-from-an-application) does not show any syntax highlighting although the code seems ok to me. What is the cause of it?

Tested with FF 3.6.15 and IE 8.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either add the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag to the question or add the following language hint to a new line just before your code block (hint should have 0 indentation):

`<!-- language: java -->`

Comment: is there anywhere a list of supported languages/scripts?

Comment: @Lipis, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one/81973#81973

Comment: Can't get the language hint working :( The tag works

Comment: I'm a bit late to the show but I got the language hint working by leaving a blank line before and after it, without an indent, just above the code block, and exactly as it appears above - with white space as shown. Strangely considering how pedantic it is, both `language: java` and `language: lang-java` will work.