# Why is there no syntax highlight for SQL merge statements?

Tags: feature-request, bug, syntax-highlighting, sql

It seems, that Stack Overflow doesn't recognise the SQL:2003/SQL:2008 `MERGE` statement, as can be seen in my answer here:

[Oracle: Updating a table column using ROWNUM in conjunction with ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094039/oracle-updating-a-table-column-using-rownum-in-conjunction-with-order-by-clause/6094075#6094075)

or here:

```sql
merge into table_a u
using (select id, rownum rnum from table_a order by column1, column2) s
on (u.id = s.id)
when matched then update set u.sequence_column = s.rnum
```

these keywords are not recognised: `merge`, `using`, `matched`

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature request.

**UPDATE**: I was asked to look for some more keywords. I can confirm, these standard ones are not recognised either:

```sql
partition
rows
unbounded
preceding
following
row
```

And these Oracle-specific ones might be interesting too http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm

```sql
ACCESS, AUDIT, CHAR, CLUSTER, COMMENT, COMPRESS, CONNECT, DATE, DECIMAL, EXCLUSIVE, 
FLOAT, IDENTIFIED, IMMEDIATE, INCREMENT, INITIAL, INTEGER, LEVEL, LOCK, LONG, 
MAXEXTENTS, MINUS, MLSLABEL, MODE, MODIFY, NOAUDIT, NOCOMPRESS, NOWAIT, NUMBER, 
OFFLINE, ONLINE, PCTFREE, PRIOR, PRIVILEGES, RAW, RENAME, RESOURCE, ROW, ROWID, 
ROWNUM, ROWS, SESSION, SHARE, SIZE, SMALLINT, START, SUCCESSFUL, SYNONYM, SYSDATE, 
UID, VALIDATE, VARCHAR, VARCHAR2, WHENEVER
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, it looks like you're right, even with [explicitly specifying a language hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one), those keywords are still not highlighted in the appropriate colors. (View the source of my edit to the original question for details.)

However, Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting is powered by [Google's Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). It is a separate project from Stack Overflow, and maintained independently by a mostly-different set of folks.

You'll need to report this one to Google as a bug and wait for them to fix it, or submit a patch yourself. Once it's fixed in Prettify, the latest version can be deployed by the team across the network and everything will be peachy-keen.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've filed a bug report to the news group. I guess the rest will be more or less automatic for peachy-keen-ness ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Added missing SQL keywords at [revision 202 of prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=202#).  New release is forthcoming shortly.