# Why does code highlighting work in the edit preview, but not in the actual post?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

For some reason, my code highlighting works when I'm editing the question, but not in [my actual post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104395/in-a-batch-script-how-do-i-get-the-long-name-of-a-file/6104544#6104544).

[image: screenshot]

(I've tried giving it a hint; no difference.)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

The question does not have any tags that designate which rules to highlight the code.  See [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) for more information.

In that case, it would be a good idea to put a [language hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) for your code instead.  I don't know what would apply to [d](/questions/tagged/d) so perhaps you should use the default rules.

Just put in `<!-- language: lang-default -->` before your code block to override it.

Note that `d` or `lang-d` is currently not a supported language.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said I tried giving it a hint. But the last sentence seems to explain it...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I was trying to keep the answer as general as I could just in case other people were not aware of these features.

Answer (score 0):

[Specifying a language hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one) definitely works. I tried adding the hint for C to the D code, and the result looks [just like the edit preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104395/in-a-batch-script-how-do-i-get-the-long-name-of-a-file/6104544#6104544) shown in the screenshot. I say it's probably close enough.

The reason it "works" in the edit preview is that it's performing a best-guess highlight. It looks to me like it's best guess is C, which makes sense here. Once you submit the answer, it uses the question tags to determine the highlighting that is applied.

If you are really interested in getting syntax highlighting for D code, you'll need to either submit a bug to Google's [Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) project and wait for them to add it, or submit a patch yourself. More information is available in my answer here: [Why is there no syntax highlight for SQL merge statements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92352/why-is-there-no-syntax-highlight-for-sql-merge-statements/92355#92355)