# Please add syntax-hinting support for Tcl

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, languages

Jeff's answer in *[Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)* lists many languages, but Tcl isn't there; however, Tcl syntax highlighting is supported if you use the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) tag. (Ref: [How to collect the output of man command in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062658/how-to-collect-the-output-of-man-command-in-tcl)

Could we get support for syntax-hinting support for Tcl?

I'd like to be able to use

```
<!-- language: lang-tcl -->
```

Comment: @Won't, Thank you for migrating; I appreciate it :-). I posted what I think is a possible improvement to the process in the discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93440/recourse-for-bad-migrated-questions/93475#93475.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built-in support for TCL that's getting applied just because of the tag. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062658/how-to-collect-the-output-of-man-command-in-tcl/6062965#6062965) in the linked question is simply being highlighted using the `lang-default` style:

```
set output [exec man cmd-name]
```

Unfortunately, that's probably not good enough for properly highlighting all TCL code. You might try something like `lang-sh`, but the result may not be perfect, either.

Stack Overflow uses Google's [Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) project for the syntax highlighting support. It is a separate project from the Stack Exchange sites, and maintained by mostly different people.

As I advised Lukas to do [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92352/why-is-there-no-syntax-highlight-for-sql-merge-statements/92355#92355), you will have to either submit a feature request to Prettify and wait for the TCL language to be implemented, or submit a style containing support for the language yourself. Once Prettify is updated, the latest version can be deployed across the network, and you'll be able to specify `lang-tcl` hints as you please.

Comment: A side-note: while I support this question in general, when we switched to using different styles in Prettify I asked that Tcl be explicitly mapped to `lang-default` (rather than none? I forget the exact details) as default's not _too_ awful.

Comment: @Donal: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Prettify uses `lang-default` now. Do you mean that you're responsible for this change from an earlier question? Did it previously default to `lang-none`? I don't know of any other language that does that; why should Tcl be that way?

Comment: Things changed around a fair bit at the time that Prettify was introduced fully. At one point, it was most certainly defaulting to none. It may have got changed since then; I prefer to avoid fiddling around with meta-work. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Currently used `highlight.js` library seems to have a TCL support included: [SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md#L192](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blame/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md#L192), but is not mentioned in a loader: https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Can we get back to the topic of adding TCL to highlighted syntaxes?