# Markdown highlights JavaScript comments incorrectly

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering

The comments above and below `jquery(document)...` are rendered incorrectly. Here's a screenshot of the [original page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112721/combining-scriptaculous-and-jquery-in-a-rails-application):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question is tagged both [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), so the prettifier doesn't know what to do and chooses some default colorization that doesn't work well here. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) for more information.

You can add a [magic comment to specify the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one/81973#81973) before a code block. (This didn't exist back when that particular answer was posted.) You need one such comment before each code block for which you want to select a different language for highlighting.

```
<!--language: lang-js-->

    jQuery.noConflict();
…
```

(I thought this was supposed to work with `<!--language: javascript-->` too, but it doesn't. Why?)

Answer (score 2):

You can forcing the language that code block is interpreted as, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), which should fix this.

To force JavaScript, we can use `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the code block.

That said, the example question *is* tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) already, so it should automatically be doing this, but maybe the other tags were getting in the way...