# Syntax Highlighting - Two Character Identifiers

Tags: bug, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I noticed a bug/feature with the syntax highlighting where two-character **capitalized** identifiers are not being highlighted inside code blocks. This does not appear to be a problem in the case of two-letter identifiers where only one of the letters is capitalized. I.e. `System.IO` fails to highlight "IO", but `System.Io` would be fully highlighted. Example is C#:

[Two letter identifiers are black instead of green http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/2459/syntaxhighlighting.jpg](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/2459/syntaxhighlighting.jpg)

I apologize if this has been inquired upon before, I didn't see it in my brief search.

Comment: Does `Encoding.UTF8` something special that it's not been marked red? ;)

Comment: Nope I just didn't event notice it in there. I suppose it would be more accurate then to say that it fails to highlight non-camel-cased statements.

Comment: All-uppercased identifiers are usually amenend as *constants.* My IDE also highlights constants differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown does only formatting. Syntax highlighting is actually done by [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). You can report issues [over there](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list).

Comment: Should I migrate my question there then? Admins?

Comment: No, it's a 3rd party library. Just report it independently.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown isn't perfect at syntax highlighting -- usually this is because it fails to guess the language, and various languages use the same syntax to mean different things (which should be highlighted differently).

[Suggestions for improving this have been made in the pas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints)t.