# Suggestion to support code-highlighting F# snippets

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting

*I couldn't really search on `F#` (giving me all unrelated hits), so forgive me if it's been asked before.*

With currently [> 1200 questions tagged F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) on StackOverflow and with Jon Skeet having co-written one of [the most outstanding books](http://www.functional-programming.net/) on the subject, I'm slightly surprised that F# code isn't highlighted cq. recognized by the code-formatter as a separate language yet.

Suggestion: please implement a code formatter for this lovely new (not so new) language so that questions [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363184/f-how-to-elegantly-select-and-group-discriminated-unions) become more readable.

Comment: Do you know, that they use a third party lib? Maybe you are interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has been improved recently (well, at least 6 months ago), see @Jeff Atwood's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) to the question @Ladybug Killer linked to. I tested it out, and if the question you are answering or asking is tagged "f#", then it is correctly inferred to use "lang-ml". If not (for example, you are showing off how sweet F# is in a C# answer), then adding `<!-- language: f# -->` or `<!-- language: ml -->` preceding a code snippit does the trick.