# Are Stack Overflow statistics public, and do they reflect the trends of the development market in a reliable way?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I was just wondering — if these data are even publicly shared, and I don't know if they are — are the questions being asked at Stack Overflow a good indicator of development trends in the past and present? Maybe they could even be a kind of sign of which technologies have the most supporters....

Have statistics about this ever been shared by Stack Overflow publicly somewhere? Are they being shared now?

Comment: I think the site is too new to follow any trends like that.

Comment: Well, you can definitely tell which ones give programmers the most trouble.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what type of statistics you are looking for. Stack Overflow "trends" will likely reflect the same sort of activity you see in a book store. They will tell you only what is being talked about, not what is in the most wide-spread use in industry.

Technologies tend to generate a lot more questions and discussion when they are new and hot. But if you look at, for example, questions about the C-language, there is certainly a lot *more* C code in use than indicated by the number of books you see on the shelves of a bookstore… or on this site.

Comment: +1 very well put, especially the part about "talked about"

Comment: Particularly if you add the dread "OBOL" after the "C".

Answer (score 1):

As Palantir, said the data are available from the [stackoverflow community dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/) and the [API](https://stackapps.com/).

There are two caveats with the data:

- Like [Robert says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69974/are-stack-overflow-statistics-public-and-do-they-reflect-the-trends-of-the-devel/69976#69976), the data reveal what is talked about and not necessarily what is used, like a bookshop. For instance, Microsoft [said in 2009](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/Future-VB.NET) there were slightly more VB.Net developers than C# developers. But there were many more C# questions on StackOverflow.
- More specifically the data reveal what is being talked about *on StackOverflow*. There may be popular technologies whose communities just haven't adopted StackOverflow. For example the StackOverflow Markdown editor is [really bad at formatting LISP and Perl code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/41734#41734). Of course there aren't many questions about these languages on StackOverflow - but that might be caused by the bad formatting...

Answer (score 0):

Why not? I think that just by looking at the tags you can get a fair idea of what is currently most discussed. For example, the windows-phone-7 tag could be an interesting one. How can you get those data? Just look at the latest [stackoverflow community dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/)...

Comment: Or you could use the [API](http://stackapps.com).