# What is the preferred way of formatting log file-like output?

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I recently added [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902631/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-spring-core), which contained a large chunk of log file output. I found it most readable when I formatted as code:

```
LOG: User = eggtech024-PC\eggtech024
LOG: DisplayName = Spring.Core, Version=1.3.1.40711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
 (Fully-specified)
... snip ...
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Downside of this approach is that it smart-formats code constructs it recognizes, which isn't really useful.

What is the preferred way of formatting log-file like output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait a second:

```
LOG: User = eggtech024-PC\eggtech024
LOG: DisplayName = Spring.Core, Version=1.3.1.40711, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07
 (Fully-specified)
... snip ...
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

You can give hints on how to format a code block: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints). `<!-- language: lang-none -->` works fine.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was about to give. +1