# Code formating does not show syntax highlight

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I just [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692722/pdf-to-image-for-mobile-device/6694775#6694775) in SO and I realized that syntax highlight was not showing up after applying code formatting. Was this feature removed?

Comment: Maybe it can't detect the language it's written in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

to your answer; now it shows up. The question is tagged [image](/questions/tagged/image) [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) [phone](/questions/tagged/phone) [smart](/questions/tagged/smart); obviously none of these tags has a default syntax highlighting.

See the [syntax highlighting section of the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: C# isn't listed in [this master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints). Is there a better list to reference somewhere?

Comment: @bemace: Sure it's listed there (`lang-cs`). That's the list of the prettify language codes -- but usually you don't need to know those; you can just use the tag (c# in this case), and the highlighting language associated with the tag will be used.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-c# --> is correct.