# Bug in parsing Python multiline strings

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

It seems that there is a problem with parsing Python multiline strings when these are delimited by `'''`.

Here's the screenshot from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844243/is-there-a-python-library-for-custom-autocompletion/6954745#6954745):

[image]

Workaround: use `"""` instead:

[image]

Yes, I also realised by now that it should spell `its` and not `it's`...

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is an issue with auto-detecting Python. If you add the [syntax highlight hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints), for Python:

`<!-- language: lang-py -->`

Then your second scenario shows up correctly @Siva:

**Scenario #2:** With single quotes' around a comment containing a single quote

```py
def autocomplete(self, category):
    '''
    If possible, autocomplete a word according to it's category.
    '''
    root = ''.join(self.chars).split()[-1]  #The bit after the last space
```

Comment: I used (see source of linked answer) `<!-- language: python -->`... didn't realised _python_ was instead `lang-py`...

Comment: @mac that would use the rule in the python tag which is "default" because python is a webby language so posts with that tend to have html, css, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting appears to be working.

The issue here is the single quote within "it's" that hasn't been properly escaped.

This should be "it\'s". This is why using double quotes resolves the issue. Single quotes in text must be escaped when specifying a string using single quotes.
The same goes for double quotes.

The reason this is necessary is because Python does not have a true multiline comment. Using triple quotes for multiline comments is a bit of a hack where the multiline string is not interpreted. However, it is still treated as a string by the interpreter, and not escaping the quotes will cause an error the same as it would if you had intended upon using that string in any other way.