# Syntax-highlighting doesn't detect virtual as a keyword for C#?

Tags: bug, status-declined, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

The syntax-highlighting functionality for code doesn't detect `virtual` as a keyword for C#.

**Note:** This is true even if you add the hint 
`<!-- language: lang-cs -->` as per [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019).

*It does have the `lang-cs` class on it.*

### Update

According to the ticket with the team, this has been fixed.

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=167

Comment: For example, adding the syntax-highlighting hint to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655440/c-inheritance-virtual-or-override) doesn't highlight `virtual` in blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be opened as a bug against [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), since that's where it needs to be fixed if it is indeed a bug.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=167

Comment: i'm pinging this - im not sure how to ping it up more so that you guys can get this into a release.

Comment: I find this answer unsatisfactory: It should be the job of SO staff, not the OP's job, to report this issue on Google Prettify's project site. After all, it shouldn't be expected of SO users to know, or even help maintain, the components out of which the site is built. Simply referring the OP to Google Prettify sure isn't *wrong*, but strikes me as a little... lazy (no insult intended, though).