# C# syntax highlighting doesn't highlight newer keywords (including "await" and "yield")

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I noticed the C# keywords `yield`, `await` and `async` are not correctly highlighted by the C# syntax highlighter.

E.g.: [Proper use of 'yield return'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410026/proper-use-of-yield-return), [C# Socket.BeginReceive/EndReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388691/67392)

Can these keywords be added to the formatter?

Comment: Nope, this is the right place to ask.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well, not really. SE uses Google's prettify library. Bugs for that or feature requests should, I believe, be addressed there.

Comment: @Mat: are we expecting now that all SO users know how SO is built? Isn't it the responsibility of the developers to tune the tools? It may be that the library needs updating, and that they need notifying, but you cannot expect Joe Soap using SO to know this or file the report.

Comment: @Martijn: I'm just repeating what I've seen multiple times here (e.g.   http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102951/158667).

Comment: @Mat: Not sure I agree with Jeff there then. :-) In any case, this is still the right place to learn about what library is used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's also in the tag wiki for that tag you added to the question.

Comment: Expanded: it isn't just yield... (edit pending review)

Comment: @Mat: this question can serve as that answer, but discoverable based on language and keyword (ie. when a new user discovers the problem would they find Jeff's answer? I just failed to and if this had not been here would have created a new question). Remember not all duplicates are bad, if they provide another route to the same answer...

Comment: Same issue happens for SQL, though a bigger problem exists there: not all keywords are appropriate for all RDBMS flavors / versions.

Comment: Same happens for PHP and Visual Basic .NET.

Comment: Of all the close reasons to pick as a proxy for "this is a problem in an upstream library, which we can't/won't do anything about", "off topic" seems to me to be the *least* appropriate.

Comment: I looked at the Google Prettify FAQ (http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).  You can specify language: &lt;pre class="prettyprint lang-html", where lang-html could be "cs".  I tried an edit -- no luck.

Comment: Actually, I agree with the flagging now.  I flagged it as a dupe myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax-highlighting doesn't detect virtual as a keyword for C#?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102946/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-detect-virtual-as-a-keyword-for-c)