# How can I escape asterisks, so they don't change font face and colour?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I typed an answer recently, and I used a code block where I had to use a double asterisk:

```
<exclude>
    <pattern>src/main/**</pattern>
</exclude>
```

The text following the double asterisk was grayed out. I searched meta, but I couldn't find advice how to escape asterisks.

The original answer may be seen here: *[What's the recommended location for SQL (DDL) scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686334/maven-directory-structure-good-place-for-sql-ddl-scripts/7686479#7686479)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to escape it. Rather, you can use [language hints for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) to have the code block be highlighted XML instead of Java (this is inferred from the tag used in the question). Add this in front of your code block:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->
```

In this case, `lang-xml` did the job.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have found that post myself.

Answer (score 4):

While using a code block is the correct solution here, if you do need to escape something outside of a code block, use a backslash. For example, *this* is not in italics because I wrote `\*this\*`.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work in the code block, does it? I've read backslash is treated differently there.

Comment: Yes, inside code blocks backslashes have no special meaning, and they show as entered. Note that your problem here has nothing to do with escaping, but rather the choice of highlighting language.

Comment: @MaDa - In Java, `/*` is the start of a block comment, and this character sequence appears in your post.   Therefore, everything after   these characters are formatted as a comment.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Now it makes sense; I didn't know my snippet was interpreted as Java.