# Code containing HEREDOC is not highlighted correctly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Not sure if this was brought before but I noticed on several occasions that code containing HEREDOC syntax will not be correctly highlighted. Example at

- [PHP domdocument if statement for when img tag has no alt attribute or if alt attribute is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785493/php-domdocument-if-statement-for-when-img-tag-has-no-alt-attribute-or-if-alt-att/7786065#7786065)

[image]

Comment: I tried editing your answer to add the [manual syntax highlighting directive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) and that didn't work either.

Comment: I tried another edit, but also to no avail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) itself. It's already reported as [Issue 41: PHP heredoc notation not supported](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=41):

> The highlighter breaks on string specified using the heredoc notation:
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc