# Did I do my syntax highlighting wrong? If so, what is the right way?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

I tried setting a syntax type based on [Jeff's Hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/137116), but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Did I do it wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8546141/124069

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I fixed it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8546141/5)

You did **not** do it right.
The comment should not be a part of the code block, but rather inline just before the code block

Comment: Ah ha, I see. The comment should not be a part of the code block, but rather inline just before the code block... Nice

Comment: @ChaseFlorell yep yep ^_^

Comment: @ChaseFlorell haha thanks for the edit ^_^

Comment: It helps legitimize the "accepted answer". Since you did edit first and answer first. Sorry @Oded, I still +1'd your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `<!-- language: lang-js -->` comment should not be indented and needs one space between it and the start of the code.

I have done this for you.

Comment: LOL editing my edit r ya? :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - Aye Neal... looks like we were doing this at the same time :)

Comment: Haha, you both did it at the same time. Neal's edit was made just before yours... Thanks to you both.

Comment: @Oded hehe I thought there were things to prevent cross editing.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - I thought so too... bug report?

Comment: @Oded http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116877/155556

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - No idea... but you did _not_ answer the question in the title (If so, what is the right way?) ;)

Comment: @Oded :-P The OP added it himself ^_^