# Cross editing not blocked?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

Regarding: [Did I do my syntax highlighting wrong? If so, what is the right way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116873/155556)

@[Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) and I were editing the OP's post at the same time and [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) never got a message saying that the post has recently been edited and was allowed to submit his edit.

I thought this was blocked.

Comment: Could be a caching issue.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99535/unconditionally-ask-for-confirmation-before-submitting-an-edit-if-one-was-just-s

Comment: @JeffMercado interesting and useful request ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not blocked unconditionally. It's only blocked if the first edit was more substantial than the second, and Oded's was the clear winner here.

See [The editing race - the slackers always win](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ^_^