# Display language hint changes in suggested edit diffs

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, syntax-highlighting, diff, language-hints

I've recently seen more suggested edits with the edit description containing something along the lines of *"Language Tag"*. The diff for these edits shows entire blocks of code being changed, except the content of those blocks is the exact same:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/246806
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/246803
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/247138

[image: Example]

I'm guessing that these edits are adding [language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)? Is that correct?

If so, can the suggested edit diffs be updated to show the added/removed hints?

Comment: I've processed the suggested edits. I'm not sure why the user who made the first suggestion thought it was necessary to add the language hint, though. There's already an [html] tag on the question, and even with the default highlighter, HTML should be colored as HTML... oh well.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks. Yeah, I guess I've been unsure whether to approve or reject those (partially because I can't see them, and partially because I'm somewhat unfamiliar with the language hints). Most of them could probably be "Too Minor", honestly; there's usually other stuff in the post needing fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the changes in the markdown diff.
Click on the lower two-pages icon to get the markdown diff. The upper one is for the rendering diff.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The real problem behind it though is if the language tag *actually makes a difference*. Adding a language tag to a block of code which is *already* highlighted that way is not useful, and should be rejected.

Comment: True. Unfortunately you can't see the highlighting (or lack thereof) in the render diff. You need to go to the post to check :(

Comment: Sweet. I'm honestly not sure if I've ever toggled that view. If I did, it's been a while and I'd forgotten about it.