# Special code format/ highlighting/ code-escaping

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I found a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975784/jsf-navigation-does-not-work-properly). My problem now is that `/*` leads inside this codeblock to starting a comment. But it is no comment after this sign. I found this earlier, too. And I didn't find a sample her on meta.

Question zero: Where is a problem like this described/ solved her on meta?

Question one: Is there an option to have kind of escaping special characters like in some languages you use `\\n` or `"\"n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code there was being formatted as Java because of the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. I've added comments to both blocks to explicitly force no syntax highlighting on the first, and XML highlighting on the second.

---

You can check out [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) for information on how to use the syntax highlighting comments.

Comment: I see. I used this `<!-- language: -->`  in earlier edits, but forgot to conclude that it has different core highlighting/ comment's strucutre. Thanks for enlightment.