# What is the better highlighting language for HTTP Apache conf?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for the best way to highlight Apache HTTP configuration :

Here an example with `lang-xml`, which really does not satisfy me:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName myapp-homintranet.myorg.com
  ServerAlias myapp-homintranet
  
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /myapp balancer://jbosscluster/myapp stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://server01.myorg.com:8080/myapp
  
  #Conf load-balancing Jboss
  <Proxy balancer://jbosscluster>
    BalancerMember http://server01.myorg.com:8080
    BalancerMember http://server02.myorg.com:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here an example with `lang-java`, a bit better, but not yet enough:

```java
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName myapp-homintranet.myorg.com
  ServerAlias myapp-homintranet
  
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /myapp balancer://jbosscluster/myapp stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://server01.myorg.com:8080/myapp
  
  #Conf load-balancing Jboss
  <Proxy balancer://jbosscluster>
    BalancerMember http://server01.myorg.com:8080
    BalancerMember http://server02.myorg.com:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't find any extension for Google Prettify and Apache HTTP. So, is there any language closer to this syntax? Do you know another way to highlight it?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you'd prefer it to be highlighted?

Comment: I don't have some real example, ... maybe vi / vim syntax highlighting would be the best ?

Comment: You can now use `lang-apacheconf` to get syntax highlighting for Apache configurations.

Comment: @Johannes while that language is available in highlight.js, Stack Exchange doesn't load it.  There is no "apache" anywhere to be found in https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure .htaccess syntax highlighting is a very high demand form. However, the `lang-bsh` syntax highlighting looks pretty decent:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName myapp-homintranet.myorg.com
  ServerAlias myapp-homintranet

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /myapp balancer://jbosscluster/myapp stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
  ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://server01.myorg.com:8080/myapp

  #Conf load-balancing Jboss
  <Proxy balancer://jbosscluster>
    BalancerMember http://server01.myorg.com:8080
    BalancerMember http://server02.myorg.com:8080
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

At least it doesn't highlight all the URLs as comments past the `//`...

Personally, I would just use `lang-none` for plain black text.

Comment: Ideed, lang-bsh is almost suffisient. I'm waiting for other replies, but it seems that's the better answer it could be given (at least, what I was expecting)

Comment: Well, I didn't actually test them all, but a list of all the available ones you can use can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints). You're free to switch them out one by one, but if nothing there is satisfying, then no, there's nothing better you can use.

Answer (score 3):

We should be able to use `lang-apache`.  The [hightlight.js demo](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) (look in the "web" category) shows that it supports "Apache Config" now.

[image: highlight.js demo apache]

However, despite  Stack Exchange using highlight.js, this syntax highlighting does not work here. [StackExchange doesn't use all the languages available in highlight.js to keep the size of the JavaScript reasonable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355928/julia-syntax-highlighting/368443#368443).  At some point, SE may revamp how syntax highlighting JS is loaded so that all languages can be supported.