# Support Prolog in syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

As listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), Prolog is not currently supported by Stack Exchange but it is supported by the underlying library [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).

Comment: Note: We are currently not adding additional syntax highlighting languages until [additional work on our highlighting code can be done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443).

Comment: Thank you for the update and reference.