# Language selectors

Tags: feature-request

I did hunt for any previous questions on this topic and couldn't find any of relevance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I've been asking / answering questions on SO and Codereview Beta for some time now. One thing I get a little narked about is the inability to quickly select which language I want my code to display as.

While I don't really mind typing out `<!-- language: css -->` throughout the answers / questions I write, it is an annoyance that the only reference to this is in the advanced help section that I am pretty sure most people would not even read. When people are asking questions with some relatively convoluted code, even the smallest increase in readability can help dramatically and easy access to this knowledge / command could help enormously for questions being asked.

With the above in mind, is there any possibility that the language type for a code block could be selected from the toolbar? As SO and many other SE sites are code related, this makes an awful lot of sense to me. Then again, what do I know. :)

Comment: @GEOCHET apologies for the discrepancy, I noticed a lot of previous questions had that per-cursor to the question, thanks for the edits.

Comment: +1, the automatic code detection isn't very accurate and forcing a language isn't very easy. (p.s for the people who remember my deleted suggestion, it seems they [already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/181088) take the tags into consideration thanks @gobernador for link)