# Language parser/detector going wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

When inserting a code sample the language is automatically detected. However, there seems to be a problem.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/472581/revisions) for example, has VB code but instead of parsing comments (starting with ') as comments, they're treated as string literals.

Either detection is wrong, or it get the commenting wrong.

Comment: Fixed. Actually for classic ASP it should be vbscript, not VB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highlighting you see on the VB code is most likely the highlighting of the detected Javascript before it. You can however insert a specific tag to enforce the correct highlighting of the code following it. This should do the trick:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
```

Have a look at the following question for further details and explanation: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)