# Language hints for quoted code

Tags: bug, status-declined, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, language-hints

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13816952/1468366) I tried to add [language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/981/188688) for syntax formatting to code blocks quoted from the question. However, it seems they won't be honoured if I write them as a comment in my own part of the post, and if I include the hint in the qutotation as well then I have some ugly empty space before the code block. There should be a way to write these things properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrapping a codeblock (and only a codeblock) in a blockquote seems, at most, a rare edge case; to be honest I personally find it quite useless. There is however a way to achieve what you want.

`<!-- language: ... -->` hints only apply to the *immediately following* code block, which is the reason it doesn't work when the thing immediately following the language hint is a blockquote. There's however a second kind of language hint: The global override `<!-- language-all: ... -->`. This will apply the language to *all subsequent* code blocks (unless they have their own language hint, and until superseded by a new global override).

Thus adding `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` to the top of your post (and removing both `<!-- language: lang-none -->`) will do exactly what you expect.

Comment: Does it mean that if on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions) I want to quote both the JS source and PHP source when facing a problem with AJAX, I'm by design unable to do it properly?

Comment: @Mołot You'd need to give one or both of those a syntax highlighter hint, which is exactly why those hints exist - using them _is_ doing it properly.