# Quote's style changed. Is it a bug or just style update?

Tags: support, blockquote

Now quotes look like that:

> A quote.

Quote's style changed. Is it a bug or just style update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that's been changed [intentionally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes).

Appears SE network wide now.