# Change the colour of quotes to blue, grey or black?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, blockquote

> **Note:** not a duplicate of [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow)

Many people dislike the change of citation colours from yellow and orange to white and grey:

1. [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow)
2. [In memory of the Yellow CSS Box](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394516/in-memory-of-the-yellow-css-box)

I agree that yellow and orange did not fit in with SE’s web design as much as white and grey do, but...

> ...white and grey are less visible.

So I propose 3 new colours that will fit in with SE’s colour palette of white, black and blue:

#### 1. Blue

[image: Blue proposed colour]

SE’s developers would know which exact hex values would be best.

#### 2. Grey

Grey could be a more neutral alternative:

[image: Grey proposed colour]

#### 3. Black

A slight variation of grey:

[image: Black proposed colour]