# Change the colour of quote borders depending on the site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blockquote

The feedback on my question [Change the colour of quotes to blue, grey or black?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344909/change-the-colour-of-quotes-to-blue-grey-or-black) seemed to suggest that the new change to `<blockquotes>` is a considerable improvement as it looks cleaner.

But I think that the colour of

> ← **this** border

Should vary depending on the site. This is will fit in with the site's colour palette and will be more appealing, whilst still keeping the clean look.

#### Examples

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Comment: I wonder if this is something that moderator teams per-site could come to a consensus on. Then, they could bring it forward to CM's, who could relay it to developers to push forward.

Comment: What about accessibility and [colorblind users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=colorblind), each site's meta will need to discuss *which* color from their palette will be used. Also is each site's meta, example: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ to remain gray toned or is it to have a second set of colors; * over 170 sites?

Comment: The whole idea behind the new designs is to standardize, right? So this may be feasible in the future, but not now they're still working out the kinks.