# Appropriate way to refer to your own Feature Request from a related post?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, link-only-answers, duplicate-answers

I recently made the feature request [Support browser "reader views" to allow user-controlled formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353706/support-browser-reader-views-to-allow-user-controlled-formatting)

This is a standalone FR, but it is also a relevant as a potential solution (and at least as a response) to [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change) and [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow)

**What is the appropriate way to helpfully point to my Feature Request from other posts without double posting or being spammy?**

To me, the clearest way would be a short answer, briefly describing the proposed feature, with a link to the full FR.  That way, discussion related to my FR in the context of those other questions could happen there, but discussion of it on its own merits could happen at the source.  However, I can see that that might seem self-promotional.

On the other hand, I could comment on those threads -- but the comments are already very deep there, and it wouldn't quite make sense, since I'd be proposing an answer in a comment, which is also a no-no.

Finally, I could just not cross-reference at all, but since my FR is a response to those issues, that feels unhelpful.

Anyway, since this is Meta, I wanted to understand best practices in referencing a FR from related FRs, maximizing helpfulness while minimizing spamminess.

Comment: What's wrong with a link?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean: if you mean a link by itself as an answer, my impression was that that's generally considered a low quality answer. If you mean the link that is generated in the related posts column, that's not really a way of contributing to the conversation at a different feature request. Hence my question.

Comment: No, no, not a link as an answer. But a link in your question to the related question. Or as a comment under the related question, if you don't need it to be permanent.

Comment: If I post something relevant and possible solution to a question, I usually comment something like this:  "*I agree with this, and have posted a feature-request for it's removal/reinstatement.*"  Pointing to a possibly helpful post with a comment is fine.  You're not writing out the whole thing in a comment, you're just linking it.

Comment: Or, if my FR came first and has answers, then just say "Does this answer your question? (link)"