# How to hint objective-c code?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, language-hints

I have checked the [language hint list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/206648) and could not find one for objective-c.
My question is how should I give an objective-c hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially, it would be `lang-m` (it's based on the file extension), but [the prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js) then uses the same handler as used for C and C++:

```
registerLangHandler(sourceDecorator({
        'keywords': CPP_KEYWORDS,
        'hashComments': true,
        'cStyleComments': true,
        'types': C_TYPES
      }), ['c', 'cc', 'cpp', 'cxx', 'cyc', 'm']);
```

so you may as well use `lang-c`, which is what the default is for the [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `lang-c`, that's what the questions tagged [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) are getting.

(Look at the div with your favorite browser's developer tools.)