# Pascal/Delphi syntax highlighting should ignore \' escape characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting does not recognize the end of string in `'no escapes in pascal \'` because of the backslash. Example:

```
pascalString1 := 'In pascal \n and \' are not recognized but '+sLineBreak+' and ''' are.';
```

This answer demonstrates the problem IRL with `'\'` in the source:
[In-place editing of a subitem in a TListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835355/in-place-editing-of-a-subitem-in-a-tlistview)

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints, I think the fundamental issue here is that we don't include lang-pascal.js ; checking...

Comment: seems to all be in place now, btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK; I've added the `lang-pascal.js` addition into our standard "prettify" bundle, which means that this should start working after the next build. I've verified that this addition fixes the line-end issue: it does. I've also designated `lang-pascal` as the code-language for [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal) and [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi).

So: it should start working after the next build.

Note that we store the markdown => html output, so it will mainly apply for posts that are edited or created after this time.

Comment: Marc: Could this cause code-comments to break in Delphi? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171950/what-happened-to-comments-in-syntax-highlighter).

Comment: Adding `lang-delphi` to Delphi posts fixes their highlighting. Can the Delphi tag be updated to use that?

Comment: @Martin to the best of my knowledge there is no lang-delphi... I can *check*, though...