# What happened to comments in syntax highlighter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed, that comments (noticed this at least in Delphi language) are not highlighted as comments at this time. A few examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297489/960757
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15237273/960757

Notice that lines escaped by `//` chars should not be highlighted as code, but as comments:

[image]

Could you take a look on it, please ?

Comment: This *seems* to have been caused by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171666/pascal-delphi-syntax-highlighting-should-ignore-escape-characters/171673#171673

Comment: It seems to do so. It's nice to have a specific highlighter, but it broke a lot of answers now due to a missing `<!-- language: lang-pascal.js -->` tag.

Comment: `lang-pascal` should be enough. `lang-pascal.js` would apply the default guesser. The 'broken' highlighting is when pascal *is* used as the highlighter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default pascal highlighter coming from the prettify project is bogus.

Based on it, I've made a new [Delphi Google prettify highlighter](http://pastebin.com/puGMPncH) that, not being perfect, address the following issues:

- The backslash is not treated as an *escape* character in strings, so for example `S := 'C:\' + Path` now correctly ends the string.
- The three flavors of comments are recognized and correctly highlighted: `{ }`, `(* *)` block comments and *a la c* `//` end of line comments
- The list of reserved words is updated to [Delphi XE3 official list](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Reserved_Words). I decided to include only the reserved words and not *directives* (in the sense of the linked document). That excludes words like `absolute`, `override` and the like, that you may want to see highlighted. The problem here is the words are not reserved and have a special meaning only when used in certain constructions, but the language allows also to use it as identifiers (that's discouraged, but allowed). I'm not sure about this, but I wanted the job finished. Let's see the comment trail here to make a final decision.

I consider the *new* highlighter not final, but it works better than the old one. Your *bug reports* and *feature requests* are welcome.

[Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) kindly accepted it to use it here in SO while I post it to the official prettify project, as noted in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171954/149992) comments. It will be used not as lang-delphi but as lang-pascal. I'll update here if my proposal gets official acceptance.

Comment: Such contribution deserves the answer accept! Special thanks to @Marc for his job as well!

Comment: May I have a question about the highlighter ? If a reserved word is contained as a part of an identifier, e.g. `var SomeName_string_var_etc: string` it is treated as a reserved word and highlighted that way. Is there a way to fix this ? Look e.g. at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10678961/960757).

Answer (score 9):

Sigh. As noted, I don't think there is a lang-delphi. So: we have a few options:

- use lang-pascal and accept fixed string literals at the expense of code comments
- use lang-default and prefer comments to working string literals
- hope someone will volunteer a patch to lang-pascal

I'm all ears.

Update:

I've put jachguate's version in (after testing etc) as lang-pascal for now; long term this would ideally by contributed by the author to the prettify code-base (see also my comments below).

Comment: The first option is too expensive in my view. I'd prefer to break those escapes again and stop to highlight code comments. Even the answers in [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10835355/960757) linked to the [yesterday's question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171666/179541) are worse readable now (due to those highlighted comments). The third option would of course be the best.

Comment: @Marc I did once a HTML highlighter for Delphi. Please, point me in the right direction of where can I check how the highlighting is done here to check if I can contribute. Of course the third option is the best!

Comment: @jachguate we use prettify from google-code

Comment: @Marc, I've created a new lang-delphi prettify extension, and [uploaded it](http://pastebin.com/puGMPncH). I don't consider this to be final, but it fixes the commenting and problems with strings ending with a backslash (\) I observed in SO. It would be nice if others contribute with _bug reports_ to enhance the extension, but IMHO it's superior to the lang-pascal we use now.

Comment: @jachguate I've tested that and it seems to do the job; however, being pragmatic it may be preferable to propose it (to the prettify project) as changes to the existing lang-pascal one; the line between pascal and delphi is blurry and the two terms are often used interchangeably or incorrectly. I don't think the prettify project will want a lang-pascal ***and*** a lang-delphi. For now, I'm using your version **as** lang-pascal (not lang-delphi)

Comment: @Marc I asked myself that question before posting it here, but the list of reserved words also varies from the old days of Turbo Pascal, so I wasn't sure. Being user of Turbo Pascal and Delphi, I'm aware of what was changed, but I'm not familiar with free pascal or other pascal flavors. I'll ponder the idea a bit more in my head and I'll post as a proposal to the prettify project, as Delphi or Pascal in the coming days. Thanks for taking my contribution, I hope it really improves the experience here. I'll also post an answer to this question to let the OP accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's the Pascal highlighter that is at fault here.

If you add a `lang-delphi` hint the highlighting is correct:

```
<!-- language: lang-delphi -->
```

I honestly do not know if there *is* a Delphi highlighter, but the [first answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297489/100297) looks correct now that I added it. It may be that the default highlighter is better than the Pascal highlighter for these posts.

Comment: So there seems to be also a `lang-delphi` language. Though `lang-pascal` helped for this too. Well, this doesn't make me happy as I'm having a lot of posts to update now... And some people a lot more than me. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @TLama: No, don't update the posts. Let the devs alter the language hint attached to the tag instead. See [Pascal/Delphi syntax highlighting should ignore \' escape characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171666/171673#171673) where I asked Marc to use `lang-delphi` for the Delphi tag instead.

Comment: @TLama: No there is no `lang-delphi` language hint. What's actually happening is that the identifier is not recognized, so it's reverting to `lang-default`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the `lang-pascal` should be a default highlighter for the questions tagged by [tag:delphi], [tag:pascal], [tag:freepascal], [tag:object-pascal] and [tag:turbo-pascal], but that's not implemented yet.

Comment: @TLama lang-pascal is the default for delphi and pascal; I can add it to the other 3 tomorrow

Comment: @Marc, that would be great, thanks!