# Xcode-snippets make code look like its inside a comment

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow, comments, code-formatting

When asking questions on SO that involve Xcode code-snippets, the syntax is to use a #, which makes the code look like it's inside a comment. For example this Xcode standard snippet for looping through an array of objects:

```m
for (<#type *object#> in <#collection#>) {
        <#statements#>
    }
```

or this custom-made snippet:

```m
UILabel *<#labelName#> = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#x#>, <#y#>,<#width#>, <#height#>)];
```

On Stack Overflow all code after the first # will look like its commented out. An example on this bug is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661823/how-to-use-variable-name-of-a-variable-thats-set-by-the-user-when-making-a-snipp) I have asked on SO about code snippets. [More on Xcode snippets here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009975-CH14-SW1)

Comment: This isn't _quite_ a bug; it's just that Xcode [isn't supported by the Markdown language highlighter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/131713) (yet). For now, you could set your snippets to `lang-none` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I haven't ever used the snippets feature.

Answer (score 5):

This is a limitation of the Objective C highlighter.

If it bothers you, you can turn it off using [special HTML comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) - I've done this for the example you posted.

Comment: Would it be possible for the community to submit a patch to said highlighter, and get that implemented on SO?

Comment: If you get it into [Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), it should eventually end up on SO.