# Formatting Returned Errors on Stack Overflow Questions

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

How should one format returned errors or console messages in a question on Stack Overflow?

Recently I ran into a PHP question that had an error as a code block:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: 
Network is unreachable in /var/www/api/get_contents.php on line 2
```

Whatever, I guess it looks fine, but the automatic syntax highlighting kind of makes it a little bit difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting these "output" messages as code blocks is just fine. If the automatic syntax highlighting proves bothersome, you can add an [explicit syntax hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) to disable it:

```
I get the following warning:

<!-- language: lang-none -->

    PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: 
    Network is unreachable in /var/www/api/get_contents.php on line 2
```

Alternatively, you can abuse inline code formatting (using backticks), to which syntax highlighting is never applied. That would look like this:

```
`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: 
Network is unreachable in /var/www/api/get_contents.php on line 2`
```

and render like this:

`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: 
Network is unreachable in /var/www/api/get_contents.php on line 2`

Comment: Good tip on the explicit language declare. Thank you.