# left angle bracket in pre tag explodes formatter

Tags: bug, code-formatting, editor

I was trying to move the text in between the tables out of the code block in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979685/find-the-first-parent-of-a-child-record-using-mysql), but the preview refused.

```
I have a table that has ID and ParentId, I would like display each ID with its first parent, 
<pre>
  ID     | ParentId
---------|-----------------
     1   |   Null
     2   |   1
     3   |   1
     4   |   2 <-- its first parent its ID=1
     5   |   Null
     6   |   5
     7   |   6
     8   |   7
</pre>

So the query would display something like this.

<pre> ID   | first_ParentID
-------|-----------------
   1   |  Null
   2   |   1
   3   |   1
   4   |   1  
   5   |  Null
   6   |   5
   7   |   5
   8   |   5 
 </pre>
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help, I'm not very good with queries.
```

Yet, it still appears as:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the `<` was messing it up.

Comment: Get rid of the `<pre>` tags

Comment: Why are you using `<pre>`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand OP was using it. I use it regularly as well. Annoying highlighting colors for table data.

Comment: Use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` if the colors inherent from the default language bug you (this is driven by the tags). Don't mix the HTML thingy with HTML, it doesn't mix well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's more complicated then using a `<pre>` pair. I don't think the formatter should explode because there's an `<`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of defining a code block and not having it overrun with colors you don't want.

```
  ID     | ParentId
---------|-----------------
     1   |   Null
     2   |   1
     3   |   1
     4   |   2 <-- its first parent its ID=1
     5   |   Null
     6   |   5
     7   |   6
     8   |   7
```

This is done by prefixing the code block with:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

The full list of languages supported here are available in this meta question:

[Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

Yes, that is more complicated than a pair of `<pre>` tags. I'm just trying to help you with a workaround. They may take this and fix it, but they may not (as who knows what it will break if they make their code editor change its behavior / order of parsing etc., and I don't believe the code is all theirs in the first place). So if they don't fix it, or if you wait a long time for them to fix it (since there is a trivial workaround), you can use this syntax in the meantime.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't explain why the formatter explodes because of an extra `<` between the tags (especially if `<pre>` is allowed).

Comment: OK. I don't know why because I don't have source code access. I expect that parsing is out of order. In the meantime, I do have the ability to provide you a workaround. If that is not what you're after, that's ok, I can delete my answer. But it may be what another reader is after.

Comment: I think this is a valid workaround, but still seems like a bug.

Comment: I agree, that's possible. And I can't answer to that. You'll have to wait for a dev or someone with internal knowledge to know why this blows up using `<pre>` tags. Just be aware they may simply tell you to stop using `<pre>` tags.

Comment: If they tell me to stop using `<pre>` tags I just hope they remove it from their [white listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) HTML tags.

Comment: The tag itself isn't necessarily the problem, it's what you're putting inside of it. While yes, technically, a `<pre>` tag should support embedded HTML tags, you can shoot yourself in the foot this way with any of the tags. What does `<kbd><hi there</kbd>` display for you? Should it be blacklisted too?