# No syntax highlight for Fortran?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I was checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16377216/440558) on SO, and noticed that there is no syntax highlighting for the code snippet.

I realise that Fortran is a pretty obscure language, especially on SO, so I don't really expect it to get highlighting unless it gets added to Google Prettify.

Comment: This should be as easy as providing a Fortran grammar file for the google-code-prettify project. You can see other grammar files at http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc

Comment: The linked question was just edited, and apparently there is _some_ highlighting. As for fixing the rest my self, I just clicked the question because it was mistagged, I know _nothing_ about Fortran other than that it exists. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It was me who edit it. I tried `<!-- language: lang-fortran -->`, but the language is not specified [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints?rq=1). So I guess this is a default highlighting for some other languages.

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-pascal -->`  does a fairly good job, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334737/string-formatting-with-fortran) (well, apart from the strings...)

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-fortran -->` works now, due to moving to **highlight.js**. See https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

Answer (score 1):

If this is a feature request for adding a specific language to the current [set of syntax highlighting languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/168244), then you should refer to the linked FAQ:

> **Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine.** It uses [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Therefore, any bugs and feature requests regarding syntax highlighting cannot be handled by Stack Exchange and should be directed to the team behind Google Code Prettify.

In the mean time (as [suggested in comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179052/no-syntax-highlight-for-fortran#comment541176_179052)), use [`lang-pascal`](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/loader/lang-pascal.js) as a partial alternative.

Comment: You're exactly right that this is answered in the FAQ, but better to flag the question as a duplicate rather than answer it.