# Please deploy Fortran syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Fortran is supported by [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md). There are several [Fortran questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) at Stack overflow every day.
Please enable Fortran syntax highlighting.

Comment: I guess you need to make an argument that the code-bundle doesn't explode by adding support for Fortran. Performance is still a design feature.

Comment: @rene I have no way to determine the impact. I can only ask. That is what I did.

Comment: There has been [some MSO discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315269/3157076) giving additional detail.

Comment: @francescalus I knew I saw something similar before. Didn't check MSO.

Comment: This question is a legitimate [re-ask of the prior 7 year old request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179052/282094), now that we have [syntax highlighting for Fortran](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402200/3648282). See the [Highlighting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/282094) and [New Highlighter Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/282094).

Comment: January 2022: Is there any improvement for the better *since then*?  Given Fortran is in the (lower) top 20 of [Tiobe's list](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/), which is observed in the community ([a discussion](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/fortran-returns-to-top-20-tiobe-index/1069/51)) and not dead ([ongoing survey](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/research-articles-using-fortran/1101/61), but in active use and development [call for FortranCon2021](https://tcevents.chem.uzh.ch/event/14/)/[video recordings](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmrUfKC3D2ZMHLRyQANeP_Q/videos)?