# Should error logs be formatted as code or quote?

Tags: discussion, markdown, code, blockquote

When I see an unformatted error log, I format it as

```
code
```

I've noticed, however, that some other users format them as

> quotes

Which is better?

> tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 555

or

```
tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 555
```

Comment: Whatever is more readable, I think. Sometimes it's a blockquote and other times it's a code block.

Comment: When formatting them as code, add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to disable the syntax highlighter.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific instance, I think the "better" way would be:

```
tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):
Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 555
```

That is, as a code block, with a newline added by hand to prevent horizontal scrolling.

Syntax highlighting does not seem to kick in on your example, but even when it does it can sometimes have a positive effect (e.g. emphasis on numbers).

(For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125040/jquery-ui-blind-effect-reveal-from-bottom/10127387#10127387) is an old answer of mine that contains ugly ASCII-art diagrams in code blocks, and syntax highlighting actually improves things IMHO.)

Comment: In the case of your example you seem to have specifically written it knowing that it would be fed into a syntax highlighter and you adjusted the text in several ways specifically to get the highlights that you wanted.  Since most people won't be doing that, it's almost always best to have the syntax highlighting disabled.

Comment: @Servy, I can assure you I composed that answer in the raw editor without looking at the preview, using my own conventions, and was amazed single-quoted text and properly capitalized sentences ended up rendering like this :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The point still stands; in the vast majority of cases it won't render in a sensible manor.

Comment: Seems like a lot more work to go through a block of text adjusting the linebreaks.  What's the compelling reason for wanting to use code formatting and adding in that extra work?

Comment: @Servy, in this particular case, logs are usually meant to be read with a fixed-sized font, and look ugly with the variable-sized font used in quotes?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I generally don't find that to be true in the general case.  You can use `<pre>` if you want to use fixed-width font, perhaps for some specific case where it's relevant.

Comment: @Servy, true, I always forget some HTML elements are allowed in our posts (Markdown is probably spoiling me). On the semantic side of things, it looks like you consider logs to be "text" rather than "code", but my own (limited) experience makes me think the opposite :)

Answer (score 1):

I find the workflow rather simple.

Is the text code:

```
yes -> use code markdown
no -> don't use code markdown
```

Also, if you decide to use code markdown anyway, at *least* ensure that syntax highlighting is disabled so that there isn't nonsensical color highlighting.

Comment: And is an error log code, or text? Is it text telling you what's wrong with your code, or is it code telling you what's wrong with your text?

Comment: @Undo An error log is text that may or may not be referring to code.

Comment: What about when it is an error log with a bunch of code in it - like `NSString failed with double value of an NSNumber`?

Comment: @Undo I don't see code in that quote...

Comment: `NSNumber`, `NSString`, etc.

Comment: @Undo I don't really see that as code...and even if you do, it certainly is perfectly readable if not formatted as code.  Now if you have a bunch of text that isn't being rendered properly because it has a bunch of angle brackets or something like that then it becomes a different case.