# Do we have Assembly syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I couldn't help but notice that my NASM Assembly questions didn't have kind of code highlighting. Like this one: [Why is my register-constant comparison not working in NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819863/why-is-my-register-constant-comparison-not-working-in-nasm-assembly)

I used `Assembly` and `NASM` tags and still didn't work. Do we have Assembly syntax highlighting? Well, not that there is much to highlight in Assembly anyway (although it'd be nice to see my symbols and registers with a different color).

Comment: No, not according to [Syntax highlighting language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

Comment: @chuex: So it would be valid to make this a feature request?

Comment: @Omega See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/152515) on what you can do if you _want_ there to be Assembly syntax highlighting.

Comment: We need to add [MUMPS](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-mumps.js) prettifier! (Though some would contend, nothing can make that pretty)

Comment: @Omega That feature request would fall on deaf ears. Stack Exchange is not the right place to request that - [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is the place to request it.