# Why isn't this language hint working?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, language-hints

In the following answer I've inserted this language hint

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
```

However, it is not picking it up and therefore not formatting it with HTML syntax colours.

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65467/8340

Is there any reason why? I have tried just `language` before each block as well to no avail.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/241749 - `Use <!-- language-all: lang-or-tag --> to use the given highlighting for all the following code blocks.`

Answer (score 9):

Syntax highlighting is not turned on for Security.se.

We do not usually turn it on for sites that do not have a majority of posts with code in them (Lego, cooking, RPG are examples of such sites). Security tends to have more prose than code - hence, it isn't turned on.

The reason for this is that turning it on means including more JavaScript and slows everything down - performance matters to us.