# Why doesn't the syntax highlighting work?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I tried several ways of how to do syntax highlighting for R in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/438394/5509), but it doesn't work. I tried ```` ```R ```` (see [revision 3 of the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/438394/3)) and `<!-- language: R -->` (see [revision 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/438394/2)) but neither of them does work, despite the instructions in [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/166308).

PS: note that I *don't want* to tag the question with the R tag because it is not R specific.

Comment: The canonical is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)*.

Comment: I had similar with powershell, `<!-- language: lang-shell -->` resolved it

Answer (score 10):

I've just submitted a [suggested edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/245784) using the old-style code blocks and a [language hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/981/295232):

```
<!-- language: lang-r -->
```

That seems to work:

[image]

Your last version ([revision 3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/438394/revisions)) might not work since you used a capital R; language hints need to be in lower case.

Comment: Thanks! These are really catches! `lang-r` instead of just `R`! And small r instead of R - R is always written with capital R. I think the documentation needs update with list of possibilities and maybe the parser could be more tolerant as well.

Comment: It looks like [it registers both upper- and lower-case varients](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-r.js). In theory it should work but I guess there's something else in the way.

Comment: @Tomas the list of possibilities is in the linked Prettify documentation.